# Alternative to Rolle's Theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I sincerely hope this is not a dumb question. I was doing some reading through an analysis book and was looking at Rolle's Theorem. That is, if a function $f:[a,b]:\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b), and that $f(a)=f(b)$. Then $\exists c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

Now, it seems to me that the intuition here is that if the "end points" of an function's value are equal (and the function is continuous), then the function's maximum or minimum has occurred somewhere between the endpoints. However, this intuition is obviously much more general than theorem. It doesn't seem to require differentiability(or does it?).

Hence, my question is this: Is there a analogous theorem that captures the complete intuition without differentiability as a requirement? Why or why not?

As a possibly less important question:if we allow positive and negative infinity can we likewise get rid of the the continuity condition? Why or why not? Or why might this be a unimportant question?

Please let me know if I'm not being entirely clear somewhere, so I can clarify what I mean.

EDIT: I'm sorry I didn't use an example to maybe explain my question. The absolute value function has a minimum, but it is not differentiable there, but I would still like to speak about that point.

Thanks for your time and help in advance!

Comment: How do you expect to abandon differentiability and still speak of $f'(c)$?

Comment: That's just the thing. I don't want to speak of $f'(c)$ I just want to speak of maximum values of the function without $f'(c)$.

Comment: How do you talk about where a maximum or minimum occurs without differentiability?

Comment: Take a function like $f(x)=x$ if $x\in (0, 1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=.5$.  Then the function is equal on the endpoints, but does not attain a max or a min.

Comment: @user89 You don't need differentiability to talk about maximum and minimum. For example $f(x)=|x|$ has a minimum.

Comment: @Valentino But then it's just the [Weierstrass' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), except for a few cases.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. That's exactly what I just said in my edit. You read my mind.

Comment: @GitGud That was what he's asking - Weierstrass is an *answer* to this question.

Comment: @Thomas Okay just looked it up! Thanks Thomas that is exactly what I was looking for. Now, for my less important question. What if we allow discontinuous functions, and plus or minus infinity as values for maximums or mins

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do I know that the minimum/maximum doesn't occur anywhere else on $|x|$ apart from $x = 0$ without differentiation?

Comment: If your function is discontinuous you may not have any max/min (see my previous comment).

Comment: Rolle's theorem doesn't say anything about where you find a minimum/maximum. I might not be following your point. @user89

Comment: @ThomasAndrews One cannot talk about continuity without talking about differentiability?

Comment: Asking me a question that might or might not be rhetorical doesn't help to clear up your previous comments. Try to explain succinctly. @user89

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's a question, not rhetorical. I am not good at math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Extreme Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem):

> For any continuous $f$ defined on $[a,b]$, there exists $c_1,c_2\in[a,b]$ such that for all $x\in[a,b]$ $f(c_1)\leq f(x)\leq f(c_2)$.

We get a continuous version of Rolle:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)=f(b)$ then there exists an $c_0\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c_0)$ is either the minimum or the maximum value of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

**Proof**: If $f(x)$ is constant on $[a,b]$ then you can pick any $x_0\in(a,b)$.

Otherwise, assume $f(c)>f(a)$ for some $c\in(a,b)$. (The second case, $f(c)<f(a)$, is the same.) By the Extreme Value Theorem, there exists $c_0$ such that $f(c_0)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Since $f(c_0)\geq f(c)>f(a)=f(b)$, we know that $c_0\neq a,b$, so $c_0\in(a,b)$.

---

Rolle's theorem follows from this by the proof that, if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ then a maximum or minimum on $(a,b)$ must have derivative zero.

Comment: This is called the Extreme Value Theorem (Weierstrass generalizes it to compact spaces if I'm not mistaken), which I think is found in most calculus textbooks. In any case, this is the best answer.

Comment: Oops, quite right. I followed the Wikipedia link in comments above, and didn't read it carefully, so its statement of the EVT at the beginning got me confused. Will fix. @TimClark

Answer (score 1):

There is a theroem that states something pretty close to what you want :

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b$ and $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ continous over $[a,b]$.

Then, $\exists m, M \in [a, b]$ such that $f([a, b])=[m, M]$ and hence :
$$\forall x \in [a, b], m \leq f(x) \leq M$$

However, from the moment $f$ is not continuous, this is not necessarily true. e.g. $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, f(-2) = f(2)$ but it has no maximum on $[-2, 2]$.

Note also that Rolle's theorem is different, it does not say that there is a maximum but more specifically that there is a value for which the derivative is $0$ (which is why it needs the function do be differentiable).

If you allow $±\infty$ to be maximum/minimum values, this won't change anything. They can be infimum and supremum but not maximum and minimum because your function will never reach it.

Another example is for instance the function $1-e^{-x}$. It will never reach one, so one is not a maximum.

Comment: Rolle's theorem isn't really stronger, since (1) it doesn't assert the value is a maximum or minimum, only that it has derivative $0$, and (2) it is very easy to prove that a maximum or minimum has derivative $0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : It is not possible to prove that a maximum or a minimum has a derivative $0$ since it is not the case for all minimums and maximums.

Comment: Sure, but it is true for all inside $(a,b)$, if $f$ is differentiable. Basically, Rolle's follows trivially from Weierstrass, and it's statement doesn't assert anything stronger.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Because it follows from Weierstrass doesn't mean it is weaker. Maybe isn't it stronger indeed, but Rolle's is somehow more "user-friendly". (That is my point of view..) (btw, I edited accordingly to your comment)

Comment: But it certainly isn't stronger in any sense.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Which is why I edited ! =)